Fatal Exception in RCTCxxBridge.mm after migrating to New Architecture of React-Native
A non-std C++ exception is reported by Crashlytics for 5% of the users after migrating the app to new Architecture. Please note that it is not reproducible on debug builds and happens rarely in lower environments.
The issue occurs on load of the app and repeats for the same user on the app downloaded from appstore
The issue is reported only on iOS builds. Find below the stack trace of the Crash
Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: non-std C++ exception
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e88 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  TSC                            0x6b2f88 RCTFormatError + 167 (RCTAssert.m:167)
3  TSC                            0x6ca740 -[RCTCxxBridge handleError:] + 1123 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:1123)
4  TSC                            0x6c90a0 __34-[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]_block_invoke + 668 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:668)
5  TSC                            0x6dd080 facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 72 (RCTMessageThread.mm:72)
6  TSC                            0x6dce2c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void ()>) + 45 (RCTMessageThread.mm:45)
7  CoreFoundation                 0x43564 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK
8  CoreFoundation                 0xabd9c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
9  CoreFoundation                 0x7bb98 __CFRunLoopRun
10 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
11 TSC                            0x6c6e30 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 332 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:332)
12 Foundation                     0x5b808 NSThread__start
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc _pthread_start
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start
Note that the issue is not commonly reproducible and gets reported by Crashlytics for around 5% of the total users.
Would help if we could get any pointers towards fixing the issue as this is bringing our Crash-free % down.
